# What's the name of this bug from Toronto, Canada?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

[image: Mystery bug]

It's about 3 millimetres in length. Found on September 10, 2015.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a moth fly. They're cute fuzzy little things. Most people consider them pests.

[image]

> An annoying and troublesome pest that concerns numerous homeowners is the moth fly, also commonly known as the [drain fly, filter fly, or sewage fly](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/moth-flies-in-the-home). Moth flies are frequently found indoors on windows, sinks and walls.

They're often found around sink drains because the eggs and larvae survive on the biofilm in your, well, drains.

Answer (score 6):

This IS a Moth Fly (Family **Psychodidae**), but the heavily-patterned wings and their posture at rest argue against the genus *Psychoda*; the pale spots at the wing margins suggest *Clogmia albipunctata* (Williston, 1893) which has been extending its northern range limits (half a century ago, this species and Toronto mentioned in the same sentence would have been considered a likely misidentification; [this](https://diptera.info/forum/viewthread.php?forum_id=5&thread_id=56248) diptera.info thread discusses two localities for that species that are even further north -- Clallam and Grant Counties in Washington).