# What kind of drain fly is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

**Habitat:**  Men's room at a rest stop in Syracuse, New York.

**Size:** ~1 cm

Based on my limited searching ability, I think it's a type of "drain fly" (Psychodomorpha): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychodomorpha

Hard to get a better picture without a macro lens, but is anyone able to speciate this fuzzy urinal-fly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the same species as is featured in the question "What's the name of this bug from Toronto, Canada?" (see: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38665/whats-the-name-of-this-bug-from-toronto-canada); there the question has two answers.  As further support of the answer I gave there, see the diptera.info thread https://diptera.info/forum/viewthread.php?forum_id=5&thread_id=69927, where a European specimen is identified to species by an expert (the species is VERY widely distributed!)

Comment: Interesting to hear about it's expanding range.  When I first saw it I wasn't sure if I should call it a moth or a fly, that "moth fly" description fits well. I feel sorry for its sad little life around the urinals :(