# What insect is this with furry wings?

Tags: entomology

Found this on the wall of my house in Kuching, Sarawak, MALAYSIA It is a tiny black triangular shaped insect.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the name of this bug from Toronto, Canada?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38665/whats-the-name-of-this-bug-from-toronto-canada)

Comment: Very nice macro. I really like the looks of these things and hate to kill them. :-( I keep my drains free-ish of biofilm so I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Moth Fly, also known as a Drain Fly. It is in the order, Diptera, family Psychodidae. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain_fly

Comment: Here the animal's appearance helps in a more precise identification: we're looking at a species of _Clogmia_ Enderlein, 1937 (see [here](https://bugguide.net/index.php?q=search&keys=Clogmia&search=Search) for the only New World species of the genus); this _may_ be _C. albipunctata_ (Williston, 1893), but southeast Asia also features native species (for the original descriptions of several New Guinea species see Pacific Insects Monograph (15), accessible [here](http://hbs.bishopmuseum.org/pim/)).